# Unknown behavior when creating plists

Tags: iphone, ios

I am currently using XCODE 4.0.2 and am trying to create a very simple plist as shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5)

I follow the instructions telling me to do the following!

it should end up looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>John Doe</string>
    <key>Phones</key>
    <array>
        <string>408-974-0000</string>
        <string>503-333-5555</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

however. when i do it, it ends up this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <Key>Root</Key>
    <dict>
         <key>Name</key>
         <string>John Doe</string>
         <key>Phones</key>
         <array>
            <string>408-974-0000</string>
            <string>503-333-5555</string>
         </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

is this a bug between 4.0.2 and 4.2 (or whatever the lastest version is?) what accounts for this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's sample is wrong.  The graphical view shows Root but the text view is a flattened version without the Root parent.  Just don't include the Root node when you create the list and you'll end up with text that matches their listing.